# FileNames listing duplicates?

Tags: files-and-directories

Every time I use FileNames on Windows 10, it lists a nonexistent duplicate file containing an extraneous "._" in front of the filename like so:

```
files = FileNames[All, NotebookDirectory[], 2];
TableForm [FileNameDrop[#, 6] & /@ files]
```

Output:

```
{
 {"copied from mac"},
 {"copied from mac\\20190816A_AL-Full_Spray_a82"},
 {"copied from mac\\._morphoFiltering.nb"},
 {"copied from mac\\morphoFiltering.nb"},
 {"copied from mac\\._SEM_porosityReconstruction.nb"},
 {"copied from mac\\SEM_porosityReconstruction.nb"},
 {"Erica's Images"},
 {"Erica's Images\\20181207A"},
 {"Erica's Images\\20181207B"},
 {"Erica's Images\\20181207C"},
 {"Erica's Images\\20190422A"},
 {"Erica's Images\\20190422B"},
 {"Erica's Images\\20190422C"},
 {"._SEM_porosity_Erica.nb"},
 {"SEM_porosity_Erica.nb"}
}
```

This does not occur on my MacBook.  How can I make it stop listing these duplicates?

Comment: The “copied from Mac” has the clue: those files are apparently linked to MacOS and used internally; they remain hidden there but, once you copy them to a Windows system, they lose their special status and show up in your file listings. Mathematica is doing nothing wrong here. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980

Comment: oh wow.  that makes sense.  thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about operating systems and file systems, not Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a duplicate. It is a separate, hidden file. If you enable showing hidden files in Windows Explorer, you will see it.